# where to find or how to set htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title in project created with vue cli 3?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, typescript, vue.js

I wanted to set title to my webpage created with vue cli 3 and thus looked into `public/index.html`. There, I found `<title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>`.

How do I set and modify `htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title` in vue cli 3 project?

Comment: That'd be configurable via [`pages`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages).

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Looking at the popularity of the question, I decided to add an elaborate answer with references to make it more authentic and complete. I have also created [an article](https://medium.com/@mayank-1513/how-to-set-htmlwebpack-plugin-options-title-in-project-created-with-vue-cli-e686087646df) on this topic and covered this topic in [this](https://www.udemy.com/course/vue-3-essentials/?referralCode=E6D2FDE2B8B06C1991F1) and [this](https://www.udemy.com/course/vuejs-complete-course-plus-guide/?couponCode=HAPPY_LEARNING) courses.

Though the question is looking for setting `htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title`, the ultimate effect is changing the title of the web-page.

## 1. Most convenient and trivial solution

The simplest way to do this is to modify the `public/index.html` and hard-code the title.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title>
        <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %>
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
</body>

</html>
```

This is the default `public/index.html` that is generated by vue cli. And in this, you just need to change

```
    <title>
        <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %>
    </title>
```

to

```
<title>Title of your choice</title>
```

## 2. Change the `name` field in `package.json`

Another simple solution is to change the `"name": "your-project-name"`. However, there are many restrictions on the `name` you can use in `package.json`. You can read more about this [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file). Basically, `package.json` must contain a name and that must be lowercase and one word, and may contain hyphens and underscores.

## 3. Using `pages` field in `vue.config.js`

`vue.config.js` is an optional file that you can add to provide additional configurations to Vue CLI and this file, if present, will be automatically loaded by Vue CLI. You need to create `vue.config.js` in the root folder - the folder containing you `package.json` file.

According to [Vue documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages), you can use pages field to define entrypoint for multi-page app. However, you can also use this to define title for single page app as well. Create `vue.config.js` in the root directory and add `pages` field to your exports as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    index: {
      // entry for the page
      entry: 'src/main.js',
      title: 'My Title',
    },
  }
}
```

Note that if you are already running development server, this change will be reflected only when you stop and restart the development server. In other words, these changes will not be hot reloaded.

## 4. Chaining Webpack

You can [chain Webpack](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#chainwebpack) in `vue.config.js` as shown below

```
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config
            .plugin('html')
            .tap(args => {
                args[0].title = "My Vue App";
                return args;
            })
    }
}
```

Note that similar to solution 3, this change will be reflected only when you stop and restart the development server, in case you are already running development server. In other words, these changes will not be hot reloaded.

## 5. Modify title in lifecycle hooks using JavaScript

The next solution in the list is to use JavaScript to modify the title. You can do this either in `mounted` lifecycle hook of your root component or if you want different title for different routes, you can do the same for components loaded by each route.

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      //
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    document.title = 'new title'
  }
}
</script>
```

## 6. Use Vue Meta

Finally you can use [Vue Meta](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/) to manage all metadata for your Vue app including title. First you need to add Vue Meta to your project and then use `metaInfo` field as shown below to configure metadata for your page or route.

```
{
  metaInfo: {
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { title: 'My title'}
    ]
  }
}
```

## Conclusion

The first 4 solutions are static ways of changing your title or in other words you can't change your title at runtime using these ways. Also all of these are not hot reloaded. The last 2 options use JavaScript and can manipulate the title at runtime.

Comment: For some reason, none of the above solutions seemed to work on my Vue 3 / Vue CLI 4 project. In the end I was able to update the title, as well as the other meta info, using [@vueuse/head](https://github.com/vueuse/head)

Comment: Is setting the document.title in mounted() ok for SEO?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. For SEO you may want your app to render statically or server side. Or at least have meta-tags available without needing to run any JavaScript on client side.

Comment: I used approach #3 suggested by you. In my case, [vue.config.js] looked a little different. I added the pages collection like this:

const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')

module.exports = defineConfig( {
    transpileDependencies : true
  , pages : {
        index : {
            entry : "src/main.js"
          , title : "Identity Verification Client"
        }
    }
} )

Answer (score 64):

create a file `vue.config.js` at the root

```
//vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config
            .plugin('html')
            .tap(args => {
                args[0].title = "My Vue App";
                return args;
            })
    }
}
```

see https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#modifying-options-of-a-plugin

Comment: Above answer works perfectly, just remember to restart your npm or yarn

Comment: Why just not add `<title></title>` tag in `index.html`?

Comment: @jeand'arme it is related SPA logic. On each route changed, title is considered to be changed

Answer (score 22):

Update the **name** property in your **package.json** file

```
{
  "name": "URL-friendly_app-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Update:
The above mentioned method will only work if you use a URL friendly title.

There are a couple of other ways to do it

- From the Vuejs official documentation [Pages Configuration](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages), you can use the html plugin configuration to specify the title for different pages
- Use the environement variables [Modes and Environment Variables](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes) to hold your app/page title. I personally prefer and use this method.

**.env** (or any .env.[mode])

```
VUE_APP_NAME=Application flixible name
```

And this is how you call it in different places in your app

**AnyComponent.vue** (as a data property)

**TypeScript**

```js
appName: string = process.env.VUE_APP_NAME
```

**Javascript**

```js
appName: process.env.VUE_APP_NAME
```

**anyHTML.html**

```
<%= process.env.VUE_APP_NAME %>
```

Comment: package.json does not support non-url-compatible name

Comment: That's true. I'm updating the answer to show more options.

Answer (score 1):

Just correcting one of the scripts with the green check

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      //
    };
  }
  mounted() {
    document.title = 'new title'
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `vue-pwa` plugin, the `name` is set within the `site.webmanifest` file.

Answer (score 0):

I have simply assigned value fo `htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title` something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title="WebStore" %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and I think the best way is to update the **name** inside the **packer.json** and you need to restart your app

*package.json file:*

```
{
  "name": "my title app",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using vue router you can do it through the router's index file. In the `router.beforeEach` method you just have to change the `document.title` to your routes title.

```js
const DefaultPageTitle = "Default title"

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
    {
        path: "/",
        name: "home",
        meta: {
            title: "Your Title"
        },
    },
}

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    setPageTitle(to);
    next();
});

function setPageTitle(to: RouteLocationNormalized) {
    const hasMetaTitleString = typeof to.meta.title == 'string';
    if (!hasMetaTitleString) {
        return document.title = DefaultPageTitle;
    }

    return document.title = to.meta.title as string;
}
```